# Framework for mobile web app (quiz game)

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile, ionic-framework

I´m developing a mobile quiz web app for smartphones, which will NOT be transformed into a native app.
It should run on as much smartphones as possible.

I came across ionic, but it seems with its css-transitions-only approach a bunch of devices are left out.

Would it be safer to use jQuery mobile?

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not looking to add your app in App Store or Play Store then it's not recommended ([official forum post](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/deploy-ionic-app-as-a-website/2845)) to even consider Ionic.

If you're *just* making a mobile app (and you seem to say so) then jQuery mobile would be a perfect fit (I used it before and it's great for this purpose).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to Construct 2. I am making a quiz in Construct 2 with a nice result!

Comment: I also thought about using PIXI, as I used it before but as this will not be demanding on the graphical side, i thought it would be faster produced with html/css/js.